# warning: unable to access 'git://mirror.xxxx.co.za/xxxx.git': Invalid argument

Tags: git, gitblit

everyone, I have been having this issue lately with **GIT**

> C:\Grit\Source\v1\xxxx>git add -A
>   warning: unable to access 'git://mirror.xxxx.co.za/xxxx.git': Invalid argument

I have tried all the StackOverflow solutions but no luck yet...

Please help! 
Many thanks.

Comment: Would you post the command, what you are trying to do? You're doing a mistake while using the command with an improper argument.

Comment: Hi, the command is 'git add -A' ...I want to stage all the new files, deleted files as well as the modified files.Thanks you

Answer (score 0):

First please read the error message.

It says 'invalid argument'. From your question it's not really clear what you're really want to do. But try `git add` without `-A`. 
For further information please read [this](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add).